# Android activity resume

Tags: android, android-activity

I use code below to start an `activity`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(XXX.this, YYY.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(data);
```

somehow, I don't know why, XXX's `onResume()` method is invoked.
and because I try to pop up a `progressDialog` inside `onResume()`, I got below error:

```
`android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity XXX has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@406ca468 that was originally added here.`
```

In debug mode, I set a `breakpoint` at the first line of method `onResume()`, it never stops there, but still I get the above error.

why does this happen?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling startActivity(intent), not startActivity(data)?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2850573/844882

Answer (score 0):

Because onResume is part of the Activity lifecycle, it will be called regardless of whether this is the first time your Activity is being created. If you want to open a dialog when the user returns to it, you should probably put that behaviour in onRestart, not onResume.

Edit: Without seeing your dialog creation code, it's hard to say what causes the error. However, make sure you are placing a call to showDialog and returning a created Dialog from onCreateDialog, not just creating the Dialog itself in onResume.

Comment: it is mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.notice_login_server), true, false);

Comment: if Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT is used, onresume is called instead of onrestart